# can I install realm object server on Windows platform?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-object-server

How can I install realm object server on my windows platform?

I tried using the npm command-line. It installed but the server didn't start.

It threw this error:

> module.js:544
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\DAMILOLA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\realm-object-server\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v59_win32_x64\realm.node'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)    at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)    at Module.require
>   (module.js:585:17)    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)    at
>   Object. 
>   (C:\Users\DAMILOLA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\realm-object-server\node_modules\realm\lib\index.js:102:28)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)    at Module.load
>   (module.js:560:32)    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)    at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature for this on GitHub, but its state is open (see link below)

It looks like they intend to make this work in the future, It doesn't look like you can at the moment.

https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/46#event-854032531

It looks like you have a few options available to you in terms of hosting this online, or in a virtual machine perhaps? more details on the link below

https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

> How can I install realm object server on my windows platform?

Realm Object Server runs on Ubuntu 16.04 x64 (amd64 when you download it), and Mac OS.

> Supported Platforms
>
> - CentOS 6
> - CentOS 7
> - Ubuntu 16.04
> - Ubuntu 17.04
> - macOS 10.10+
>
> You must also have a 64-bit CPU (x86_64 architecture on Linux).

See [here](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/developer-edition/#installing-realm-object-server).

---

So to run it on Windows, you'll need to install VirtualBox, and install an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 on that virtual machine. That's how I used ROS (and Realm Studio) on my home PC, too.